# Determining opponents card magic trick

Tags: puzzle, card-games

You have a standard pack of $52$ cards.

Your opponent takes $5$ cards at random from the deck and hands them to your partner.

Your partner looks at the cards and gives you $4$ of the cards one at a time before giving the 5th card to your opponent.

You can now tell your opponent what his card is with 100% accuracy.

Assume the only way you know your opponents card is through the order in which your partner gave the $4$ cards to you.

What is the strategy used so you can always correctly name your opponents card based on the order the $4$ cards are given to you?

---

I figure that with $5$ cards and only $4$ suits you have to have a repeated suit and therefore you can determine the suit based on a specific card given to you.

I am not sure how you can give the value of the card using your remaining $3$ cards. Alternatively the 4th card has more meaning than just telling the suit?

---

Apparently this strategy can be applied to a higher number of cards, $n$, for which all $n$ are mutually distinguishable. What is the value of $n$?

Based on this extra part to the question I figure the suit part of the $52$ pack of cards is actually not necessary to create the strategy.

All suggestions on where to go with this is appreciated.

Comment: This has a good answer at [puzzling.se](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/20379/five-card-magic-trick-with-n-card-deck)  It works for $124$ cards.

Comment: A strategy was posted on [Reddit r/math](https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/7l1t84/a_combinatorists_card_trick/) a few days ago.

Comment: If you're allowed to show $n$ cards only, you can use a deck of size $n! + n - 1$, as proved [here](https://web.northeastern.edu/seigen/11Magic/Articles/Best%20Card%20Trick.pdf).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read comments with links to proof as to how this works and why maximum is 124.